# Apache proxy on port 443 connecting properly, but not returning data to client

Tags: apache, sockets, httpd.conf, mod-proxy

I'm trying to forward WSS requests on port 443 to a listening service.  I've *almost* got a working forwarder/proxy via Apache's `mod_proxy` module.

The websocket client (in a browser) shakes hands, and connects with via forwarded port.  But then **the client does not receive any data back**. It seems like it's working *one* way, but not sending responses/data *back* to the right place.

Seems like a routing issue.  Here are my `httpd.conf` settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/prod/domain
    ServerName domain.com
    ErrorLog logs/prod-error_log
    CustomLog logs/prod-access_log common

    SSLEngine On

    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem

    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia On

    ProxyPass /radio wss://172.31.47.171:8082/
    ProxyPassReverse /radio wss://172.31.47.171:8082/

    ErrorDocument 403 '<h1>Unauthorized Access</h1>'
</VirtualHost>
```

And the client connects using:

```
var host = 'wss://domain.com/radio/';
socket = new WebSocket(host);
```

Finally, the socket-handling process connects on:

```
172.31.47.171:8082
```

After reading everything I can on this, it feels like this is likely an issue with `ProxyPass` or `ProxyPassReverse` - but I've tried everything I can think of at this point.

The port-listening script shows a successful 'client connected' message when the browser handshakes with the port-listening script, but then just has a pending request hang forever - no data comes back.

Environment settings:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Amazon)
Amazon Linux EC2
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction (even to just debug where it *is* sending responses) I'd appreciate it!  Nothing in the error logs that I can see - just no data coming back to the browser.

---

Edit:

So, abandoning SSL in favor of just the plain `ws:` protocol fixes the issue - but obviously it doesn't use `wss`.  I'm still looking into why `wss:` is not sending back any data.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to encrypt and terminate the ssl layer at the proxy (https) when the underlying is already ssl encrypted (wss). In fact, all hardware proxies, use TCP (not http nor https) when proxying for ssl traffic. When proxying http traffic, that's when ssl terminated proxy is useful.

Comment: Not sure if you saw the edit I added before you commented, but I'd like to NOT terminate the SSL layer and keep it encrypted all the way there and back, but the client is only able to receive data if I use `ws:` instead of `wss:` with the configuration above.  Did you have a suggestion for how I can get `wss:` receiving data?

Comment: I think you misunderstood what `terminate SSL` means. In `SSL` lingo, `terminate` refers to the device that handles the `cert` and negotiates the key with the client. The proxy in your case does this, hence it terminates the `SSL`. Now, between the proxy and the `wss` server, is the connection encrypted? Is the application running on port `8082` accepting SSL connection? If not, then you cannot forward traffic to `wss:`.

Comment: You have 2 options, keep the SSL proxy but forward to `ws:` or make sure the process listening on port 8082 can accept SSL connection if you want this process to terminal SSL. Or maybe this application does listen on SSL, but in a different port.

Comment: Thanks, 'termination' was new nomenclature for me. Just to be clear, if my client (an HTTPS page) sends data to the reverse proxy and onward to the listening port and data is returned to the HTTPS page - all via `ws` - then someone sniffing on the same network will see unencrypted data via `ws` protocol, correct?

Comment: Between the client and the proxy, everything is encrypted. Between proxy and websocket, everything is clear. Only those can be sniffed. This is not an issue if this segment of network is secured, meaning, no unauthorized users in the network segment. And won't be an issue if both proxy and websocket are running on same host. In this scenario, websocket should be listening on localhost.

Comment: Here's how it works. Client requests connection to proxy. Proxy sends public key to client. Client encrypts wss: requests with public key then sends to proxy. Proxy decrypts requests. Proxy forwards request to ws:. WebSocket accepts request. WebSocket, returns reply to proxy. Proxy encrypts result with client public key. Proxy sends result to client. Client receives result and decrypts it.